# Button with focus - run function on 'Enter'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my code below.  It's doing what I want.  What I want to also do is run this function when a user use their keyboard to tab to the .add-row button and then presses enter.  How do I make that run?

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-row', function(e) {
  $( this ).html('Hide').removeClass('add-row').addClass('hide-row');
  $( this ).parent().parent().next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is you want the button to have focus and the user to press enter to fire the event, yeah?  If so, then using the `:focus` pseudo class selector on the `.add-row` should work with the `keypress` event

```
$("body").on("keypress", ".add-row:focus", function(e) {
    var ENTER_KEY_CODE = 13;
    if (e.keyCode === ENTER_KEY_CODE)
    {
        alert("Enter key pressed");
        // perform hide row and other operations here
    }
});
```